# Find all files in directories named foo

Tags: find, directory

I would like to find all files which reside in any directory `foo`. For example, consider the following files:

```
foo/w
a/foo/x
a/b/foo/y
a/b/c/foo/z
a/b/c/foo/bar/n
```

I would like to find the files `w,x,y,z` and get them listed as above, i.e., with their relative paths. My attempt was something like

```bsh
$ find . -path '**/foo' -type f
```

which doesn't work. The search should not include file `n`, i.e., only files whose parent directory is named `foo` we are interested in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not using `find`, but globbing in the `zsh` shell:

```
$ printf '%s\n' **/foo/*(^/)
a/b/c/foo/z
a/b/foo/y
a/foo/x
foo/w
```

This uses the `**` glob, which matches "recursively" down into directories, to match any directory named `foo` in the current directory or below, and then `*(^/)` to match any file in those `foo` directories. The `(^/)` at the end of that is a glob qualifier that restricts the pattern from matching directories (use `(.)` to match regular files only, or `(-.)` to also include symbolic links to regular files).

In `bash`:

```bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob

for pathname in **/foo/*; do
    if [[ ! -d "$pathname" ]] || [[ -h "$pathname" ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$pathname"
    fi
done
```

I set the `nullglob` option in `bash` to remove the pattern completely in case it does not match *anything*.  The `globstar` shell option enables the use of `**` in `bash` (this is enabled by default in `zsh`).

Since `bash` does not have the glob qualifiers of `zsh`, I'm looping over the pathnames that the pattern matches and test each match to make sure it's not a directory before printing it. Change the "`! -d || -h`" test to a "`-f && ! -h`" test to instead pick out only regular files, or just a single "`-f`" test to also print symbolic links to regular files.

Answer (score 3):

I'm on RHEL 7. This works for me:

```
find . -path "*/foo/*" ! -path '*/foo/*/*' -type f
```

Note the DOT before the -path. (Or substitute your path there, such as /home/$USER)

The *DOT* says "Start looking in the current directory"

the *-path* says "Look for anything, followed by a sub-directory named foo, followed by anything"  except for directories nested under "foo".

The *-type f* says give me only the *files* in a matching directory.

Looks like

```
-path "*/foo/*" ! -path '*/foo/*/*'
```

Doesn't get everything as it misses things like `./a/foo/b/foo/c`.

If you can guarantee that file and directory names won't contain newline characters, you could post-process the output with `awk` like:

```
find . -path "*/foo/*" -type f | awk -F/ '$(NF-1) == "foo"'
```

Comment: That is pretty close to what I'm locking for. I updated my question in order to be more precise. This solution finds any file whose path contains a directory named `foo`. However, I'm interested only in files whose parent is named `foo`.

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that. I'll work on an update.

Comment: I think @Jeff added that. Thanks for that!

Comment: Note: `a/foo/c/foo/z` should be found.

Comment: Just updated the answer to show that.

Answer (score 3):

`**` has no special meaning in `find` patterns. `-path '*/foo/*'` would find all files under a directory called `foo`, including files in subdirectories. `-path '*/foo/*' ! -path '*/foo/*/*'` would exclude files like `a/foo/b/foo/c`. I don't think you can do this with just one invocation of POSIX `find`.

With `find` implementations that support `-regex` (GNU, BusyBox, FreeBSD, NetBSD), you can use that to ensure that there's a single `/` after `foo`.

```
find . -regex '.*/foo/[^/]*' -type f
```

Alternatively, you can use `find` to locate the `foo` directories and a shell to enumerate files in this directory.

Another potential approach would be to invoke `find` again, but I can't find a pure POSIX `find` solution that actually works. With any POSIX `find`, invoked again for each `foo` directory:

```
find . -name foo -type d -exec find {} -type d ! -name foo -prune -o -type f \;
```

Beware that this mostly works, but not quite, and it's a little fragile. You need `-type d -prune` to avoid recursing into subdirectories, but with just `-type d -prune`, find would stop at the `foo` directory. `! -name foo` does not prune `foo/foo`, so a file like `foo/foo/bar` will be reported twice. You can't use `-exec` in the inner `find` because its `{}` would be interpreted by the outer `find`. If your `find` has `-maxdepth` (which is being considered for inclusion in the next version of POSIX), you can make this reliable, but there's still this limitation against `-exec`:

```
find . -name foo -type d -exec find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f \;
```

With any POSIX find and sh:

```
find . -name foo -type d -exec sh -c '
    for x in "$0/"* "$0/".*; do
      if [ -f "$x" ] && ! [ -L "$x" ]; then
        …;
      fi;
    done
' {} \;
```

Substitute the code you want to run on the file names for `…`.

Comment: One way to nest `-exec`s is to use a shell as in `-exec sh -c 'for file do find "$file" -exec cmd \{\} +; done'  sh {} +`

Comment: And the `-prune` problem can then be addessed with `find "$file/." ! -name . -prune...`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sure but for this particular example, if you're going to use a shell, you don't need a nested `find` invocation at all. I was discussing a find-without-sh solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee that file and directory names won't contain newline characters, one method is to find all files, then use `grep` to match  only the desired results:

```
find . -type f | grep '/foo/[^/]*$'
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is:

`find $ROOT_PATH -type d -name foo | xargs -n1 -I{} find {} -type f`

Comment: Unfortunately, this also finds the file `n`, which should be excluded since it lives in `bar`, not in `foo`.

Answer (score -2):

Tried with Below approach

```
find  . -type d -iname "*foo* -exec ls -ltr {} \; 2>/dev/null| awk '!/^d/||/^l/{print $0}'
```

Comment: Unbalanced double quote. Also note that the output format should be a pathname, not a filename.